# Opening SWFUpload dialog w/o using a flash button?

Tags: javascript, flash, swfupload

SWFUpload has a parameter where you specify the button to be clicked to open a dialog.

Is there a simple way to manually open the dialog box without the use of the SWFUpload-provided button?

Main thing is I have multiple places on my page where I want an image to be replaced via SWFUpload and I don't really want to instantiate a new SWFUpload class in every place I want to do an upload.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a way, but it doesn't work in flash 10, therefore obsolete.  For a non-flash solution, ajaxUpload is a good one.